# Search a String excluding html tags in body HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

If my html is like this

```
  <body>
  <b><span>jQuery</span> 
               is designed to change the way that you write 
  <span><i>JavaScript</i></span>.</b>
  </body>
```

How can i search for string

```
  jQuery is designed to change the way that you write JavaScript // This is a Dynamic string
```

in body html and wrap it with a `<span class="we">` tag..

Please help me on this..

Comment: Is it a dynamic string you're looking for, or is it always structured with the span and i tags?

Comment: this is a dynamic string comes with predefined tags..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `$(htmlString).text()`.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this.. I dont have idea on $(htmlString)

Comment: $(body).html() = <b><span>jQuery</span> is designed to change the way that you write <span><i>JavaScript</i></span>.</b>

Comment: @slaks Yes, I can understand jquery but what i am asking is I am asking you for an Idea to achieve this..

Comment: @SLaks, Need to wrap body in quotes. $("body").text().

Comment: @PrathapReddySV: `$(some string)` will give you a jQuery object containing the elements in that string.  You can then call `.text()`.

Answer (score 0):

Place this code in the header of your page (making sure you also have the jquery library referenced):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('b').wrap('<span class="we"/>');
    });
</script>
```

If you need to be more specific, place a class on your b tag so it looks like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('b.wrapme').wrap('<span class="we"/>');
    });
</script>

<body>
  <b class="wrapme"><span>jQuery</span> 
               is designed to change the way that you write 
  <span><i>JavaScript</i></span>.</b>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by getting innerHTML of element where the text is. 
In JavaScript it is:

```
document.body.innerHTML
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').contents().filter(function() {
    return $('span', this).length == 2 && $('i', this).length == 1;
}).wrap('<span class="we"></span>');
```